# Find Matrix A Representing L and Matrix B Representing L

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

So I've been going through these problems and I got the first one in the set correct, but the second two wrong. I don't know why-- my arithmetic looks fine and the steps are pretty similar.

The question is:

For each of the following linear operations L on $\Bbb R^2$, determine the matrix A representing L with respect to {e1, e2} and the matrix B representing L with respect to {u1 = (1, 1)^T, u2 = (-1, 1)^T).

b) L(x) = -x

This is just applying a -1 to x, right?

$$A = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}$$

$L(u_1) = (-1, -1)^T, \quad L(u_2) = (1, -1)^T$

Inverse of u1, u2:

$$B = \pmatrix{-1/2 & -1/2 \\ 1/2 & -1/2}$$

Then I do U^-1 * L(u1, u2) and I obtain B:

$$B = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$$

However, B is wrong. The answer is:

$$B = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}$$

Can someone explain why this is? I'm sure I'm following the book's steps correctly.

Comment: I can't tell what you were doing after you found $A$, but here's what you *should* have been doing.  Either $(1)$ find the representation of the $L(u_1)$ and $L(u_2)$ wrt the basis $U=\{u_1, u_2\}$ and then find the matrix which takes $[u_1]_U = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$ to $[L(u_1)]_U$ and the same for $u_2$ OR $(2)$ find the change of basis matrix $P$ from $U$ to the standard basis and then your matrix $B$ will be $B=P^{-1}AP$.  Use either method to find $B$.

Comment: Note however that there's a shortcut with that second method (because this transformation happens to be a particularly easy one).  Just look at the equation $B=P^{-1}AP$.  If $A=-I$ (and it does, doesn't it?), do we really need to find $P$ to figure out $B$? ;)  Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Isn't finding the representation of the linear operator with respect to U just plugging u1 and u2 into the linear operator...? That was what I was told to do, though apparently that's not the case. How would I find the change of basis matrix P from U?

Comment: So... you don't want to use the shortcut?

Comment: Is B just -I? I'm more interested in learning the steps so I can apply this to other problems.

Comment: The change of basis matrix $P$ will just be $\pmatrix{[u_1]_{\mathcal E} & [u_2]_{\mathcal E}}$ where $\mathcal E$ is the standard basis.

Comment: See if you can understand [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478660/linear-transformations-finding-matrix-in-respect-to-a-basis-and-coordinate-chang/1478753#1478753) that I gave the other day.  It's the same type of problem (change of basis).  If there's a particular part you don't understand, let me know and I'll write up a solution.  But try to go through my answer to that question first.

Comment: Yes, I was able to follow it! That's actually a really thorough walkthrough, thank you very much! I was also able to correctly complete the rest of the questions in my problem set too.